# Parsing ISC files with python (dhcpd.conf) - iscpy module

Tags: python, parsing, dhcp

What is the best way to parse dhcpd.conf file looks like?

```
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
option domain-name "example.org"
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org


subnet 172.16.31.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    # default gateway
    option routers 172.16.31.10;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;

    option domain-name "aaaaaa";
    option domain-name-servers 172.16.31.10;
    #option nis-domain "domain.org";

    range dynamic-bootp 172.16.31.80 172.16.31.90;
    default-lease-time 21600;
    max-lease-time 43200;

    host test {
        hardware ethernet 00:23:8b:42:3f:d1;
        fixed-address 172.16.31.3;
    }

}
```

I tried iscpy module:

```
a = iscpy.ParseISCString(open('dhcpd.conf', 'r').read())
```

That module makes dictionary with option as key and string next to option as value of dict. But it isn't works well if options looks like:

```
option domain-name "example.org"
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org
```

That should be:

```
{'option domain-name':'example.org', 'option domain-name-servers":'ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org'}
```

But output is:

```
{'option':'domain-name-servers: ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org'}
```

Is the way to do it better with that or other module? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest read `dhcpd.conf`  "completely", Then according to each directive make a `data structure`, such as `dict`, or class, class is preffered , then you can parse your data.